# mod_wsgi-express slow performance

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I ve tried to configure mod_wsgi to integrate apache web server with my django 1.9 (python 3.5) application. I am working on Centos7.
It works fine but the customer complains performances are slow. It takes sometime to load the homepage. Is there any setting configuration i am missing to improve the performance?
I have read on google that modwsgidaemonprocess should have better fermormance and that it is recommended configuration?  Thgerefore I changed the httpd.conf adding the follwoing lines:

```
Alias '/static' '/home/elastic/workspace/ES_Brevetti/static'

<Directory '/home/elastic/workspace/ES_Brevetti/static'>
<IfVersion < 2.4>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>

<Directory '/home/elastic/workspace/ES_Brevetti/ES_Brevetti'>
<IfVersion < 2.4>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    Require all granted
</IfVersion>
</Directory>


WSGIDaemonProcess ES_Brevetti python-path=/home/elastic/workspace/ES_Brevetti:/home/elastic/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup ES_Brevetti
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/elastic/workspace/ES_Brevetti/ES_Brevetti/wsgi.py
```

but have noticed that the mod_wsgi-express_80 script has already modified httpd.conf and cannot return back.

Indeed when I try to start apache with the command systemctl start apache i get the error : 
AH00111: Config variable ${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY} is not defined httpd: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load ${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_version.so into server: /etc/httpd/${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_version.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Any help please??

Rgds valerio

Comment: The ``mod_wsgi-express`` script should not touch your existing Apache installation. The only way that could occur is if you wrongly ran ``mod_wsgi-express`` with the option ``--server-root /etc/httpd/conf``, which you should never do. If you have done that, you are going to have to somehow uninstall Apache and its configuration files and reinstall them from system packages to try and restore the files to the originals. Also note that if using your system Apache and using system mod_wsgi, you do not need mod_wsgi_express.

Comment: How much time does the server take to respond? What is the load of the server? How many requests per second does the server get?

Comment: Thanx Graham, this is the top of my httpd.conf file:
    <IfModule !version_module>
    LoadModule version_module '${MOD_WSGI_MODULES_DIRECTORY}/mod_version.so'
    </IfModule>

    ServerName localhost
    ServerRoot '/home/elastic/mod_wsgi-express-80'
    PidFile '/home/elastic/mod_wsgi-express-80/httpd.pid'

    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
    DefaultRuntimeDir '/home/elastic/mod_wsgi-express-80'
    </IfVersion>

    ServerTokens ProductOnly
    ServerSignature Off

    User ${MOD_WSGI_USER}
    Group ${MOD_WSGI_GROUP}
Which process has modified it in that way? Thanx for ur help

Comment: Hi Antonis, we are still in test phase so pretty few requests but never 2 requests simultaneously. It takes up to 10 seconds to load the home page(specially with internet explorer).

Comment: As I said before, you have totally mucked up your normal Apache configuration because someone ran mod_wsgi-express with the option ``--server-root /etc/httpd/conf`` when they shouldn't have. There is no reason why mod_wsgi can't perform as well as or better than uWSGI when things are set up right, but your Apache setup has just been messed up too much.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to move from Apache to Nginx with uwsgi application. Performance are 100 times faster.

Thanx

Comment: what happened to you to decide to switch to nginx?